# Transform R object to a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Hello I have something like :

```
head(GC)
scaffold_1_0 scaffold_1_1 scaffold_1_2 scaffold_1_3 scaffold_1_4 scaffold_2_0 
   0.2724118    0.2747212    0.2770053    0.3061377    0.2905548    0.2865044
```

in R

```
class(GC)
"numeric"
```

I guess it is a list ?

and I would liek to change it as a dataframe

I tried :

data.frame(GC)
but I get only one column instead of two

```
                    GC
scaffold_1_0 0.2724118
scaffold_1_1 0.2747212
scaffold_1_2 0.2770053
scaffold_1_3 0.3061377
scaffold_1_4 0.2905548
scaffold_2_0 0.2865044
```

I would like to get :

```
scaffolds    GC
scaffold_1_0 0.2724118
scaffold_1_1 0.2747212
scaffold_1_2 0.2770053
scaffold_1_3 0.3061377
scaffold_1_4 0.2905548
scaffold_2_0 0.2865044
```

Comment: `data.frame(scaffolds=names(GC),GC)`

Comment: you can use `stack(GC)`.

Comment: If you have a data.frame you can use tidyr library

    `dt <- data.frame(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4); tidyr::gather(dt, key = "letters", value = "numbers")`

or data.table:

    `dt <- data.table(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4); data.table::melt(data = df, variable.name ='letters', value.name = 'numbers')`

If you have a list:

    `df_list <- list(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4); df <- unlist(df_list)`